# How do make the trackbar working as same as zooming trackbar in excel

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-interface

I am creating a report in which i want to make a trackbar working as same as trackbar in excel to zoom the report. am using trackbar. In this case minimum value is 10 and maximum value is 400. 100 is default value. now i want show my trackbar just like a excel zooming trackbar.

Comment: Are you creating your own application? In that case, what are you using; WinForms, WPF, Web application? What is this "report" you speak of?

Comment: @Patrick I am using WinForms and spread grid for report. i want trackbar working and display like a excel zoom trackbar

Comment: Have you tried using a Slider control, and setting some zoom property of the report control when the value changes?

Comment: @Patrick already i used that. minimum value 10 and maximum value 400. in that case the centre postion is how to set 100. am using trackbar only

Comment: I don't know what "centre postion" is. But why didn't you write that in your original question? You really need to expand your question on what you have tried and what exactly did not work.

Comment: What is your problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: in excel zoom trackbar thump show in centre with default value 100 and the centre postion only have a tick. i want that kind of display